# Google Maps Or Open layers thinks i'm on IPHONE?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openlayers

Came into work this morning and found this new window popping up in my google maps api v3 data layer on openlayers. Does anyone know what it is or where it comes from? Seen it before? The code points to a bunch of images and classes labeled i-phone so i suspect one of these APIs thinks i'm on an iphone.

This is the box that is popping up:
[image]

Here is the code that is generating the box:

```
<div style="position: absolute; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; z-index: 1100; overflow: visible; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: default; width: 300px; height: 180px;" class="olLayerGoogleCopyright olLayerGoogleV3"><img style="width: 300px; height: 180px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; position: relative; opacity: 0.9;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/iphone-dialog-bg.png"><div style="font-weight: bold; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 5px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; font-size: 16px; width: 290px;">Map Data</div><div style="position: absolute; font-family: inherit; bottom: 15px; cursor: pointer; background-color: transparent; border: 0pt none; padding: 0pt; margin: 0pt; font-size: 14px; left: 90px; width: 120px; height: 40px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 120px; height: 40px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/iphone-dialog-button.png"><span style="color: white; text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: transparent; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding-top: 10px;">Close</span></div><div style="color: white; text-align: center; font-size: 14px; position: absolute; left: 25px; top: 45px; width: 250px;"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  This seems to have fixed it for me.  I changed this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
```